# I have bad print quality, what should i do?

Tags: print-quality

[image]So I have an issue, every time I try to print anything it basically looks like a comb. All around the model there are just holes and holes everywhere. I dont know what to do about it. I don't have any infill, but honestly, this is just all stacked ontop of itself, so it shouldnt need to be filled in.

Please help me figure out how to make sure that the layers are actually layers, not just sticks standing up into the air.

[image: Print]

Comment: I hope you have a better image to show us, but what you describe could be massive under extrusion, the kind you get if you slice with 2.85 mm filament while you print with 1.75 mm.

Comment: @0scar I added a new picture. Do you believe that its under extrusion still?

Comment: @Ka_Ekim: Your problem looks like **exactly** what 0scar said. Not sure which slicer you're using, but it can be hard to get Cura to accept that you're using a printer with 1.75 mm filament rather than 2.85 mm,even though 1.75 is so much more common and arguably much better, because Ultimaker's printers use 2.85...

Answer (score 1):

The images that you show are typical for heavy under extruded prints. The "comb like structure" is caused by extrusion of too little filament which balls up to a certain point in time that it sticks to something previously printed, then balls up again, etc...

Under extrusion can be caused by many things, but this much is usually caused by an incorrect filament diameter set in your slicer. But, it can also be caused by a mechanical (or electronic) defect like a slipping extruder caused by a loose gear or missing steps.

I'm operating 2.85 mm and 1.75 mm 3D printing machines (both have pros an cons) and occasionally I've experienced exactly the same results (you call it a "comb" like print). E.g. the slicer Cura (Ultimaker software product) is known/used to be known to reset the filament diameter to the default of 2.85 mm after an upgrade of the software, which is the filament diameter used by Ultimaker printers.

---

*If you add more details to your question, we can tailor the answer to your specific issue, but it certainly is under extrusion.*

Comment: I have not had a chance to run any test prints, but yeah, Cura was using the wrong diameter, so now that that is fixed i hope all goes well. Thank you so much for all your help!